# youtube video in a bootstrap modal just shows a blank player

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

This bootstrap code to place a youtube video in a modal just shows a blank player in a modal. I passed the $banger variable to the modal code but it doesn't show the video. What's going on..?

```
 <!-- Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="Video_One" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
 <div class="modal-content" >
 <div class="modal-header">
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;     </button>

 <h3 class="modal-title" style="background:tan; margin:0 auto" id="myModalLabel"></h3> 

 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">

 <div class="flex-video widescreen">
 <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $banger; ?>?&amp;fmt=22&amp;autoplay=0;HD=1;rel=0" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
 </div>

 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Button trigger modal -->
 <a href="#" <?php $banger="sgr-1_chRMc"?>data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Video_One">test 1</a>

 <a href="#" <?php $banger="Yqbj9xLugU8"?>data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Video_One">test 2</a>

 <a href="#" <?php $banger="g4oMfY7q-Uo"?>data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Video_One">test 3</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to execute PHP code on the client side

```
<?php $banger="sgr-1_chRMc"?>
```

You should reconsider doing this with JavaScript. You should bind this to the modal on show event

```
$('#Video_One').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // get the video id from the clicked link
  ..............
  // apply the id to src
  $('#Video_One').attr('src', 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + video_id + ?&amp;fmt=22&amp;autoplay=0;HD=1;rel=0'

})
```

Comment: I don't quite understand. Do I just place this code in script container at the bottom of the page? How to I "get the video id from the clicked link" ? Could you explain a little more, please? Could you show a basic example of ".............." ?